# Hiding TreeView items

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I've been trying to just hide items from a TreeView. I'm using a custom data type as source (called SettingsMenuItem) which inherits from FrameworkElement (currently FrameworkContentElement, because otherwise the TreeView renders them wrong).

My goal is by setting the `VisibilityProperty` of these FrameworkElements to either `Collapsed` or `Visible` that I'm able to hide certain items (including their children). I know that this can be done by deleting items from the source collection. But that's not what I want. It would mean that I have to mirror each collection in order to keep track of it's actual items, bind to each one in order to be notified about `Visibility`-changes and create a new collection each time one changes. A lot of overhead for this.

Right now I have no clue how I could accomplish that. I figure it's related to the ItemsGenerator, but I haven't seen any possibility to override it's behaviour. I thought TreeView would be able to detect Visibility, but obviously it doesn't. As alternative I thought of a custom TreeViewItem (maybe even TreeView if necessary) - but at this point the abstraction of this whole system overwhelms me. I don't know where to start and what is actually necessary to solve the problem.

Tips what I have to change or implement by myself would be more than enough. A complete solution would be nice.

Comment: Need to see a bit of code to suggest a fix. Do you have a HierarchicalDataTemplate written in XAML you could include in your question?

Comment: This doesn't feel like the usual way to do this. Usually filtering is done by using ICollectionView & setting a Filter predicate. With a TreeView this is slightly more complicated - as you need to have a ICollectionView in each of your data types. You shouldn't need to inherit from FrameworkElement. Unless you are rolling out some crazy custom TreeView that is greatly different from the existing one, and you can't represent that difference by replacing Templates. But, I can almost guarantee, you don't need to be doing this.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I already thought that. I don't strictly use MVVM but I know that it doesn't really make sense not using it (or at least some things of it) with TreeViews and other data-view controls. Anyway, I solved it the way you suggested @user3690202: I used a CollectionView which uses an delegate specified in each instance to filter out those which should be hidden.

Comment: @SharpShade Good stuff man, I'm glad to hear it. It is always good when people move to doing things in the recommended way. Then everyone wins :)

Comment: @user3690202 I actually used `CollectionView` quite a few times. But too rarely that I memorized using them for this case. They're really handy, I wouldn't know any reason not to use them. And I didn't know that `ObservableCollection` actually does imply using CollectionViews.

Answer (score 15):

You can do this using a data trigger bound to a property (e.g. "IsVisible") in you tree data nodes:

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

While this technically answers your question I would be wary of actually doing it. User3690202's comment is correct, it's the sort of thing you would normally do via filtering in your view model.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. I used the suggested method using CollectionViews.

Comment: I think I'd add that, whilst this is "the sort of thing you would normally do via filtering in your view model," it's reasonable to do in the View in many instances too. The view is responsible for presenting the data; if the designer has good reason to choose the "not at all" option (perhaps to replace with something else?) based upon some basic criteria, then that's also fair.

Answer (score -1):

> For alternate solution using code behind xaml.cs:
> To Remove a specific TreeViewItem from a TreeView which is created from a code behind.

```
   TreeViewItem treeViewItem1 = new TreeViewItem
           {
               Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed,
           };
```

use the code with TreeViewItem you want to hide in a if condition to hide specific TreeViewItem Header let say "Cars" and you want to hide it and use the code with if condition to hide "Cars" TreeViewItem.